# Docker python3: can't find '__main__' module

Tags: python, docker

When I run

> docker-compose up --build

I get the following error:

```
web_1  | /opt/conda/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in 'glm-plotter'
```

glm-plotter/glm-plotter.py:

```
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'B0er23j/4yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?Rh'
    app.run()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpq-dev \
    build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN cd glm-plotter
RUN ls glm-plotter
CMD ["python3", "glm-plotter"]
```

Comment: Did you mean to run `python3 glm-plotter.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If glm-plotter refers to [this](https://github.com/jdechalendar/glm-plotter) repository, then according to its documentation you should run 
`python glm-plotter.py`.

Accordingly, you should change your Dockerfile to:

```
CMD ["python3", "glm-plotter.py"]
```